# Copy/Paste of Reactjs-Popup Example from the site does not work with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reactjs-popup

I'm trying out example code provided by Reactjs-Popup at https://react-popup.elazizi.com/controlled-popup/, but it doesn't seem to work.  I pretty much copy/pasted the code.  What am I missing?  I can make the popup to work if I remove all references to "useState".

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import ControlledPopup from './ControlledPopup';

const test=ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('popup'));
test.render(ControlledPopup);
```

**ControlledPopup.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';

const ControlledPopup = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const closeModal = () => setOpen(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" className="button" onClick={() => setOpen(o => !o)}>
        Controlled Popup
      </button>
      <Popup open={open} closeOnDocumentClick onClose={closeModal}>
        <div className="modal">
          <a className="close" onClick={closeModal}>
            &times;
          </a>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae magni
          omnis delectus nemo, maxime molestiae dolorem numquam mollitia, voluptate
          ea, accusamus excepturi deleniti ratione sapiente! Laudantium, aperiam
          doloribus. Odit, aut.
        </div>
      </Popup>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ControlledPopup;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the way you're trying to render your component in `index.js`.
Since if I try to render it the way I'm used to, the code you've provided worked.

I implemented it like this:

*index.js*

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

*App.js (here I use your provided component)*

```js
import ControlledPopup from "./ControlledPopup";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Popup Test</h1>
      <ControlledPopup />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check out this [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-benji-ec10hx?file=/src/App.js) for the whole implementation.

Comment: Copy/Pasted your codes, and it works.  So I changed mine in index.js to render in {StrictMode} and it works too.  Strange how my other components don't have any issue, but this popup has to use {StrictMode}.  Thanks for your help. ++

Comment: Also, I noticed on the demo site, the background dims when the modal opens, but it doesn't when I try.  Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, because I can remove strict mode from my example and it still works fine (you can check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-booth-c2b2lh?file=/src/index.js)). And I'm not sure but as far as I know strict mode is just for extra warnings while developing (_somewhat_ like -Wall for gcc). Here are the  [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) on strict mode.

Comment: The dimming probably has something to do with your styling, since there is none in my playground project. That would be my guess.

Comment: Actually I misread. I don't see any dimming in my example. So I'm not sure why you do. Might be something browser specific?